# iFrame Embedding Alternatives for Dynamic Email Content

Tags: html, email, iframe, embed, html-email

Can anyone provide some recommendations and methods for embedding dynamic content into an email?  Specifically, I want to embed a Drupal Views block into the footer of emails - ideally, I would just place a framed block, but that won't work.

I also want to avoid anyone having to grant permission - I need it to load upon open.

Images are not necessary.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Its going to be an up hill battle. Emails block content to stop tracking. You could dynamically generate content from the Drupal view.

Comment: There is an article on Litmus where they did a real time twitter feed in emails. They created an external CSS file that loaded every 10 seconds. You can read more about it [here](https://litmus.com/blog/how-to-code-a-live-dynamic-twitter-feed-in-html-email). One think i have in mind and want to test is creating a document in PHP and serving that into emails. That PHP document can load every 5 to 10 seconds to serve a different content each time. Hope that was helpful.